# Jquery Accordion causing Multiline textbox behave abnormally

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, accordion, multiline

I am facing a strange issue in my web application; I have implemented an accordion using jQuery plug-in, everything is working fine except for two multi-line textboxes.

When the page is loaded, some of the text in muti-line textbox disappears. However, when I click on the same textbox, I am able to see the complete text (Please refer attached images).

This only happens in IE, and not in Firefox/Chrome browsers. This also doesn't happen when I disable the jQuery accordion. jQuery code for accordion:-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function () {   

        $("#accordion").accordion({
            active: 0,
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Sorry, I am not able to post images.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: IE 8, Its also happening in IE 9

Answer (score 1):

Assumes the script is loading before the page completely loads. Try the script in window load

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

 $(window).ready(function () {   

     $("#accordion").accordion({
        active: 0,
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Aneeshraj, but it didn't helped.